# How to upload dependencies to a artifactory server

Tags: spring, maven, gradle, artifactory

I'm a freshman here,and I'd like to ask a question about dependency in deploying a gradle project.
I've got an offline developing environment,so when I try a spring sample built by **gradle**,i try the **artifactory** in order to resolve dependencies.
Here's what I've done:

1. deploy **gradle**,download project spring-integration-kafka-master and run`gradle build` in cmd in a PC connected to the Internet,finish downloading dependency files and building the project successfully.
2. deploy artifactory(oss 4.3.2) and run it,sucessfully login the local web page
3. modified `build.gradle`

   ```
   apply plugin: 'maven'
   uploadArchives{
       repositories{
           mavenDeployer{
               repository(url: "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local"){
                   authentication(userName: 'admin', password: 'password')
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. run `gradle uploadArchives`

Actually it works,but the artifactory got  BUILD-SNAPSHOT like this
[artifactory web page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uTcB.png)
which I **cannot resolve my dependencies** in another offline computer(I export the repository and import it to artifactory in the offline computer).
There might be some misunderstandings of dependency or gradle concepts,I hope you can help me out.
Sincerely,shimima

Answer (score 2):

If you already have 2 Artifactory instances running, put one in your "durty" environment, and [configure Gradle to resolve dependencies from it](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+with+Gradle). It will cache the dependencies that you need automatically.

Then, by using [replication](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Replication) (or export–import) transfer the artifacts to the  other Artifactory instance, than runs in the "clean" environment and configure your internal Gradle users to resolve from this internal instance.

Comment: Thank you for your time first.According to the documentation page and video in it,I figure it out.I will share the problem I met and solution in detail later.By the way,the user guide page is wonderful,it really helps.